# Saving Images in a folder using for loop

Tags: c#

I want to save images in a folder C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example using a for loop. 
and I want also the name to save like this:
Sample.jpg, Sample1.jpg

Any idea how can I implement it?

Here's my code snippet:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();

        using (var ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame())
        {
            if (ImageFrame != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg");

            }
            _capture.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: I think all of the answers below are correct (not sure if `i` is auto casted to string, maybe some of the answers should correct this and manually cast `i`). The only problem I see here is if there's any chance that a name already exists, like `sample6.jpg` for some reason already exists and you want to try and save the image changing the name to `sample7.jpg`, in this case you have to do a bit more than I see in the answers below but you better tell if this scenario is possible.

Comment: what i want to do is if i click the button, the image will save as sample0.jpg and if i click the button again, the name should be sample1.jpg

Comment: Based on your comment I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this something like this:

```
List<Image> imageList = //Get all the image list
for(i=0; i<imageList.Count;i++) 
 { 
   ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\ExampleSample"+i.toString()+".jpg");           
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
string root="C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample";
for(int i=0;i<value;i++)
{ 
    string path=root+i+".jpg"; ImageFrame.Save(path);
}
```

and better debug more.

Comment: what i want to do is if i click the button, the image will save as sample0.jpg
and if i click the button again, the name should be sample1.jpg..

Comment: for(int i=0;i<value;i++)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(""))
                    {
    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        path=root+i+".jpg"
                        break;
                    }
                }
    ImageFrame.Save(path);

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment if you simply want to just save to a different filename each time you could do something like:

```
private int filenumber = 0;

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    using (var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture())
    using (var ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame())
    {
        if (ImageFrame != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
            ImageFrame.Save(String.Format(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample{0}.jpg", filenumber++));       
        }   
    }
}
```

Note that this code just not check of the pre-existence of a file and may throw an Exception if it already exists. Ideally you should check first using `File.Exists(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The [EMGU CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) library creates a capture image from the capture device and then you manage it however you like.  Your example is attempting to save an image on a button press and is not iterating through a collection of images.

What you might want to look into is a `counter mechanism` that you maintain.  For example either when you press your button, or at application initialisation, you read the `directory` containing your images and parse the names to determine the name of the last image saved.  Obtain the `number` part of the image name and use that to initialise your `counter`, then each time your button is pressed to save an image, increment the counter.

A simplified example below:

**Counter**

```
private int lastSaveCount = 0;
```

This needs to be somewhere both your `Button_Click` event and the **Initialise Counter** mechanism below can access.

**Initialise Counter**

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Example\", @"Sample*.jpg").ToList();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var split = Regex.Split(file, @"[a-zA-Z]{1,}([\d]{1,}).jpg", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var save = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(split[1], out save))
    {
        lastSaveCount = save > lastSaveCount ? save : lastSaveCount;
    }
}
```

Place the above somewhere appropriate.

**Button Press**

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();

    using (var ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame())
    {
        if (ImageFrame != null)
        {
            lastSaveCount++;
            pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
            var filename = string.Format(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample{0}.jpg", lastSaveCount);
            ImageFrame.Save(filename);

        }
        _capture.Dispose();
    }
}
```